# DELETE rows from a table based on a condition in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete rows from a table based on a condition from a different table. I want to delete rows in `Sales` table if all the rows are same in `Final_Sales` and `Sales` table. Following is what I am trying,

My `t-sql` statement,

```
delete 
    Sales
from 
    Sales
inner join
    Final_Sales on Sales.[time] = Final_Sales.[time] 
        AND Sales.terminal_id = Final_Sales.terminal_id

-- Condition goes here. Check if they have the same records

WHERE time, terminal_id IN (select 
            time, terminal_id count(*)
          from 
            Final_Sales
        group by 
            time, terminal_id
        having 
            count(*) = 1)
```

This does not work. How can I delete the records in a table based on condition from another table?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't any better than your other question. At least the other one you finally posted some sample data. You mention duplicates but in your other post there are no duplicates. And it is not at all clear what you want to accomplish. You mention 4 tables but provide details about only 2 of them. My guess is if you would take the time to post a complete question an answer would follow not long after.

Comment: @SeanLange as posted in the other question, `#temp1` table has exactly same data as `Sales` table and `#temp2` table has exactly as `Final_Sales` table. That is the reason I did not want to copy paste the same data again. Also, for now, I don'r have any duplicates, but if I get duplicates, then I want to the delete and drop. If you want duplicate I can copy and paste the same data twice to show! We can take it to chat if you have time!

Comment: OK. You have four tables all with data right? post the ddl and some sample data for all four tables. Then demonstrate what those tables should look like after you finish.

Comment: Maybe sit down and write out a row by row type of flowchart? Not trying to be a pain here I just don't get what you are trying to do. And I must not be alone because nobody has responded on either of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow multiple expressions on the left side of the [`IN` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql).  The `IN` operator syntax is:

```
test_expression [ NOT ] IN   
( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]  
)
```

`test_expression` is any expression.  An [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql) is "a combination of symbols and operators that the SQL Server Database Engine evaluates to obtain a *single data value*." (Emphasis mine)

The query could gather up the selected Final_Sales rows first and then delete the Sales rows that match.  One way to do this is with a CTE:

```
;with FinalSales (time, terminal_id, count) as
(
    select time, terminal_id, count(*)
    from Final_Sales
    group by time, terminal_id
    having count(*) = 1
)
delete Sales
from FinalSales
inner join Sales
    on Sales.[time] = FinalSales.[time] 
    and Sales.terminal_id = FinalSales.terminal_id
```

Comment: I will try this, quick question, why is that `;` before starting with statement? I have seen the same in other answers where they start `CASE` statements.

Comment: In future editions of SQL Server, a `;` will be required to terminate every SQL query.  The `WITH` CTE statement is one of the newer statements that requires the prior statement to be terminated with a semicolon.  That is why many examples show the semicolon immediately before it.

Comment: "Although the semicolon is not required for most statements... it will be required in a future version."  Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql